# Ensuring unique combination of many to many mapped entities in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a following SqlAlchemy models with association table. They represent chat conversations. Each chat can have 0 - N users involved:

```
class Chat(BaseDbModel):
    __tablename__ = "chats"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)        
    users = relationship("User", secondary=chat_user_association, back_populates="chats")
    ...

class User(BaseDbModel):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    chats = relationship("Chat", secondary=chat_user_association, back_populates="users")
    ... 

chat_user_association = Table(
    'chat_user',
    BaseDbModel.metadata,
    Column('chat_id', Integer, ForeignKey('chats.id')),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id')),
)
```

There is nothing that would prevent me from creating multiple chats with same set of user ids. I would like to prevent this behaviour from ever happening, ideally on the database level.

**Example of intended behaviour:**

> I would like to be able to create chats with user ids {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, but it shouldn't be able to create an another chat with user ids {2, 1, 3} since that would result in duplicity.

What would be the cleanest solution / approach? I can do a manual check when creating the chat object, but I would prefer an approach that would be more race-condition proof. I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: The cleanest solution might be to rethink the definition of _chat_. Does a chat comprise all communication between a set of participants or might subject matter also be relevant? What happens when a third particpant needs to be added to a chat, but a chat between those three participants already exists?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be sorting the user IDs, to make their order deterministic, and using them to create a unique identifier. Store that in a required unique column alongside chat id.  Something like this:

```py
# Creating strings like "1-2", "1-2-3":
user_ids_key = '-'.join([str(user_id) for user_id in sorted(chatting_user_ids)])
```

Then in your table you'd add a column like:

```py
class Chat(BaseDbModel):
    __tablename__ = "chats"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True) 
    user_ids_key = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    #...
```

###### Checking/Exceptions

This will throw an exception when inserting a duplicate chat  Although it does make it easier to soft check existence before creating a new chat.  Then you need to just check for the exception but your integrity should be guaranteed.  Pretty sure this exception is thrown for both single and multiple unique constraints:

[sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/exceptions.html#sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError)

###### Maintaining integrity

To maintain the integrity of the unique key you have to be careful not to change the association table in such a way to leave the unique key out of sync.  So either chat "configurations", ie. sets of user ids, are immutable or you have to lock the chats table row when updating the association table.

- Using postgresql lock for update, lock the chats row, update the association table, then commit to release the lock
- You can soft check for a collision, ie. you added a user or removed a user and you already have a chat for that set of users
- What should happen in this case seems application dependent

  - Do you merge chats but somehow the messages have a user id set to NULL to correspond to a deleted user?
  - Do you use soft deletes, and the account is marked deleted?
- The nuclear solution would probably be to use a user defined database function but I always find that to be hard to maintain.  I think that would be later as an optimization.  Probably better performance and you could remove application code.  I don't have a lot of experience with them though.

###### Limitations

I guess a downside of this is that if you have many users in each chat or your ids are very large numbers then this might break down but it should be a reliable solution until that becomes a problem.

###### Other constraints

Along the same lines of keeping the db normalized but I don't think exactly related to your question, you probably want  a `UniqueConstraint('chat_id', 'user_id')` on chat and user id in the assocation table as well as to set `nullable=False` for both columns.

```py
chat_user_association = Table(
    'chat_user',
    BaseDbModel.metadata,
    Column('chat_id', Integer, ForeignKey('chats.id'), nullable=False),
    Column('user_id', Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False),
    UniqueConstraint('chat_id', 'user_id')
)
```

Comment: How will referential integrity be enforced for the IDs in `user_ids_key`?

Comment: That is a good question.  You'd have to maintain that by not breaking it at the application level.  It would not be a hard constraint.  I will try to update the answer.

Comment: @JohnH I added some notes about tricks to keep things consistent but I'm open/curious to/about other solutions.